# is there any way to random select grouping data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: uid-anchorUid-sample]

I have an uid and anchorUid relationship table named userAnchor like picture above, now I need to select some data from this table;

1. select all line where anchorUid=1, in this example, is uid 1 to 10;
2. random select 1 lines from top 15% of result in step 1, in this example, the result of uid is 1;
3. random select 2 lines from middle 35% of result in step 1, in this example, the result of uid will be random in 2-5;
4. random select 3 lines from bottom 50% of result in step 1, in this example, the result of uid will be random in 6-10;

My question is can I execute the query in one sql?

Comment: Use https://stackoverflow.com/a/70430969/10138734 but define ranges borders based on COUNT(*) and specified percents.

Comment: @AnkitSharma It's not a homework, is a question in working. I need to select all the uids that relate to the target anchorUid, and then divided the related uids into three parts, 0%-15%,16%-50%,51%-100%, and finally random select some uid from three part.

Comment: @Akina sorry I am  a newer in mysql, and I have no idea where to insert the specified percents and COUNT(*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
WITH
cte1 AS ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn
          FROM test
          WHERE anchor_id = 1 ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT MAX(rn) cnt
          FROM cte1 ),
cte3 AS ( SELECT id,
                 ROUND(cnt * percent_from / 100) + 1 range_from, 
                 ROUND(cnt * percent_till / 100) range_till
          FROM cte2 
          CROSS JOIN percents ),
cte4 AS ( SELECT id, ROUND(range_from + RAND() * (range_till - range_from)) random_id
          FROM cte3)
SELECT cte1.id, cte1.uid, cte1.anchor_id
FROM cte4
JOIN cte1 ON cte4.random_id = cte1.rn;
```

[DEMO fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=89ae108a455b5a6badd8714bea6e5ba9) with explanations for each step.

Solution is not compacted/optimized. You may do this yourself.

Comment: thanks a lot for your helping!!! But my MySQL version is 5.7, there is a little problems while I run the sqls. But I think I can find the solution.

Comment: @刘业锋 *my MySQL version is 5.7* ROW_NUMBER() can be emulated using user-defined variable (common task, use search), CTEs may be easily converted to subqueries. Instead of cte2 based on cte1 use COUNT() directly over source table.